# JQuery run automatically when autocomplete textbox selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm using AJAX to called data from another page then return it to a textbox. The trigger is came from a dropdown with autocomplete feature (You can see in [here](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox))

My AJAX is can work normally if I try it manually, but when I try to run this function when the autocomplete selected, it doesn't works.

Here's my AJAX code:

```
function getKonsumen()
{
    var selname = $("select[name=konsumen]").val();
    $.ajax({ url: "getData.php",
        data: {"selname":selname},
        type: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(output) {
          console.log(output);
            $("#namak").val(output[2]);
            $("#ktpk").val(output[3]);
            $("#emailk").val(output[4]);
            $("#hpk").val(output[5]);
            $("#alamatk").val(output[6]);
            $("#kotak").val(output[7]);
            $("#datepicker3").val(output[8]);
        }

    });
}
```

And here's my HTML for dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Customer</label>
        <div class="radio">
            <label><input type="radio" name="kons" value="" checked="checked" />Dari Daftar</label>
            <label style="padding-left: 50px; vertical-align:top;"><input type="radio" class="radioBtn" name="kons" value="baru" />Baru</label>
        </div>
        <select name="konsumen" id="combobox" class="konsumens">
            <option value="">Please Choose</option>
            <option value="baru">Create New</option>
            <?php
                $querycon = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM m_customer WHERE customer_status='1'");
                while($rowcon = mysqli_fetch_array($querycon, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                    $nik = sprintf("%s%"."04d", $rowcon['customer_no'], $rowcon['customer_id']);
            ?>
            //get customer list from DB
            <option value="<?php echo $rowcon['customer_id']; ?>" onClick="getkons();"><?php echo $nik. ' | ' .$rowcon['customer_name']; ?></option>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Last, my JQuery code for autocomplete (got it from jquery web)

```
(function( $ ) {
        $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
          _create: function() {
            this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
              .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
              .insertAfter( this.element );

            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
          },

          _createAutocomplete: function() {
            var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
              value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

            this.input = $( "<input>" )
              .appendTo( this.wrapper )
              .val( value )
              .attr( "title", "" )
              .attr( "id", "sicombo" )
              .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
              .autocomplete({
                delay: 0,
                minLength: 0,
                source: $.proxy( this, "_source" )
              })
              .tooltip({
                tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
              });

            this._on( this.input, {
              autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                ui.item.option.selected = true;
                this._trigger( "select", event, {
                  item: ui.item.option
                });
              },

              autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
          },

          _createShowAllButton: function() {
            var input = this.input,
              wasOpen = false;

            $( "<a>" )
              .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
              .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
              .attr( "id", "sicombo2")
              .tooltip()
              .appendTo( this.wrapper )
              .button({
                icons: {
                  primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                },
                text: false
              })
              .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
              .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
              .mousedown(function() {
                wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
              })
              .click(function() {
                input.focus();

                // Close if already visible
                if ( wasOpen ) {
                  return;
                }

                // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
              });
          },

          _source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
            response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
              var text = $( this ).text();
              if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                return {
                  label: text,
                  value: text,
                  option: this
                };
            }) );
          },

          _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if ( ui.item ) {
              return;
            }

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
              valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
              valid = false;
            this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
              if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
                this.selected = valid = true;
                return false;
              }
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if ( valid ) {
              getKonsumen();
              return;
            }

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input
              .val( "" )
              .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
              .tooltip( "open" );
            this.element.val( "" );
            this._delay(function() {
              this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
            }, 2500 );
            this.input.autocomplete( "instance" ).term = "";
          },

          _destroy: function() {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.show();
          }
        });
      })( jQuery );

      $(function() {
        $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
      });
```

**So, anyone can help me to make my ajax run when the autocomplete selected?**

Comment: Nah, many question solved by myself.. except this question... i gave up.. already tried everything but nothing.

Comment: And @Rasclatt, my previous question is about converting date... not about someone create a code for me... so your words about "on your previous question" maybe you can send a detail for me about "previous question". Or maybe you can help me with this problem

Comment: All I am saying it appears from your history that you may have needed questions answered in the past but now, *it seems* you may just be copying from answers given or the internet without knowing really how it works. Every time someone answers previous questions, your issues get more and more difficult to solve because you may not even know where to start to solve your own issue...so you ask another question...and so on. Just my opinion looking at some of the threads and comments.

Comment: Well, I'm just asking 2 question about this program and You judge me like that. thanks a lot dude... if i don't know how to use it, I won't get this ajax works for me, also I won't answer my question by myself too. But well, You may rather answer besides just commented here with your judgement... except it's your happiness...

Comment: So, you want to trigger something when someone clicks on the autocomplete select or when they select a value from the autocomplete select?

Comment: @jonmrich Trigger the function when someone select a value from the autocomplete select

Comment: I am not judging you, I am looking at what you have asked in the past. Prime example, someone in one of your questions asks about the validity of the code and you reply *"Yes, correct! got the code from stackoverflow"*. That tells me you are not making original code. Then above you say: *"(got it from jquery web)"*. I'm just saying, you're going to get into trouble if you don't know what the code does that people give you.

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes, I get same problem with them so I use that, but some of them, I understand how to use that. And about jquery in this question, if you see it more detail, I change some of them to made this feature works on my code. I wrote down 'got from jquery web' to made reader know what autocomplete I used in this code, because there's so many autocomplete method with jquery. Got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found answer to my problem, here's my solution, find : `ui.item.option.selected = true;` then I add this line of code to call the function when autocomplete clicked : `ui.item.option.onclick = getKonsumen();`
it's all done....

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#combobox').change(function() {
  //Do whatever you want
});
```

This will trigger any time someone changes the value of the autocomplete select box

Comment: Hello, I've already tried that before converting it to function, but it doesn't works... I change function to $('#combobox').change, and already tried $("select[name=konsumen]").change, and already tried $('.sicombo').change but no result...

Comment: I'm guessing you have more than one `combobox` element. Inside the `change` function, add `alert($('#combobox).val());` and tell me what comes up.

Comment: Nothing comes up. no error from console too.. But I tried to put it on a button onclick, it shows 7 (the ID of what data I clicked)

Comment: Try `alert("hello");` inside the `change` function. You should see the alert when you change the autocomplete select. If not, there's another problem.

Comment: No hello alert. seems like my combobox doesn't identified. But I try to select and throw to another page, it works good.

Comment: What does this mean: "But I try to select and throw to another page, it works good"

Comment: Try to post the value of my combobox, to prove that the combobox is work normally. Sorry to make you confuse

Comment: Try putting `console.log("hello")` in the function. Could be that you are blocking additional alerts from the page. If this doesn't show "hello" in the console, then the issue almost certainly is that you already have a div with the id `combobox` already.

Comment: Nothing show at console... Try to search combobox id, but it just used by this combobox... Another info: I use theme Admin LTE, does it the cause of this method doesn't works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87802/discussion-between-jonmrich-and-cross-vander).